# Partial differentiation in Riley's Mathematical Methods

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule, change-of-variable

It took me quite some time (and googling) to understand the partial differentiation technique reported in Riley, Hobson and Bence *Mathematical Methods for Physics and Engineering*, chapter 5.6 (pg. 160 in my edition).

I report it here to check if I understood it correctly, and maybe also to help someone else with my same problem.

To obtain a second partial derivative with polar coordinates (change of variables) they compute the first partial derivative with respect of x:

$$\frac{∂}{∂x} = \cos φ \frac{∂}{∂ρ} − \frac{\sin φ}{ρ}\frac{∂g}{∂φ}$$

and then (with g being the f function in polar coordinates):

$$\frac{∂^{2}f}{∂x^{2}} =
\frac{∂}{∂x}(\frac{∂f}{∂x}) = \frac{∂}{∂x}(\frac{∂}{∂x})f$$
$$=(\cos φ \frac{∂}{∂ρ} − \frac{\sin φ}{ρ}\frac{∂}{∂φ})(\cos φ \frac{∂g}{∂ρ} − \frac{\sin φ}{ρ}\frac{∂g}{∂φ})$$

but here comes the tricky passage:

> $$=\cos^{2} φ \frac{∂^{2}g}{∂ρ^{2}} − \frac{2 \cos φ \sin φ}{ρ^{2}}\frac{∂g}{∂φ} - \frac{2 \cos φ \sin φ}{ρ}\frac{∂^{2}g}{∂φ∂ρ} + \frac{\sin^{2}φ}{ρ}\frac{∂g}{∂ρ}+\frac{\sin^{2}φ}{ρ^{2}}\frac{∂^{2}g}{∂φ^{2}}$$

I was naively thinking that it was a simple multiplication and could not figure out the result.

As I understood, it is not a multiplication but rather an "application".

Let's take the first term:

$$cos φ \frac{∂}{∂ρ}(\cos φ \frac{∂g}{∂ρ} − \frac{\sin φ}{ρ}\frac{∂g}{∂φ})$$

Applying the product rule, it becomes:

$$cos φ (\frac{∂}{∂ρ}(\cos φ)\frac{∂g}{∂ρ} + \cos φ \frac{∂}{∂ρ}\frac{∂g}{∂ρ} − \frac{∂}{∂ρ}(\frac{\sin φ}{ρ})\frac{∂g}{∂φ} - \frac{\sin φ}{ρ}\frac{∂}{∂ρ}\frac{∂g}{∂φ})$$

then:

$$\cos φ (0\frac{∂g}{∂ρ} + \cos φ \frac{∂^{2}g}{∂ρ^{2}} + \frac{\sin φ}{ρ^{2}}\frac{∂g}{∂φ} - \frac{\sin φ}{ρ}\frac{∂^{2}g}{∂ρ∂φ})$$

and so on with the other terms.

I still find this notation rather confusing, but now my results are in line with the book.

Comment: The first formula should be $\frac{∂}{∂x} f = (\cos φ \frac{∂}{∂ρ} − \frac{\sin φ}{ρ}\frac{∂}{∂φ})g$

Comment: No, in the book is reported like that. There was anyway a typo in the first term, I corrected that

Comment: No matter what the book says the first formula is still wrong, there's a loose partial derivative not applied to anything. What is used in the next bit is (since the correction) the correct formula I stated used twice.

Comment: I don't have sufficient knowledge of math to be able to discuss about the formal correctness of the equation, but I do agree with you that that notation is *at least* very confusing. I keep it like that to maintain coherence with the way it's exposed in the book